# Package name missmatch

Tags: unit-testing, go, package

I am working on a project where I have created the attached structure.

under `tests->gchat_test` I have two files `init.go` and `gchat_test.go`

```golang
//init.go
package gchat_test

//initiation code
```

```golang
//gchat_test.go
package gchat_test

//testing code
```

for these files I am having the following error in VSCode

`found packages gchat (gchat_test.go) and gchat_test (init.go) in /home/<<>>/errornotifier/tests/gchat_test`

I tried from console as well just to make sure that this is not a VSCode issue

```
~/Loans/errornotifier/tests/gchat (feture/initial)$ go test
found packages gchat (gchat_test.go) and gchat_test (init.go) in /home/<<>>/errornotifier/tests/gchat_test
```

I have a similar structure for another set of tests and I didnt experience this error

under `tests->kafka_test` I have two files `init.go` and `kafka_test.go`

```golang
//init.go
package kafka_test

//initiation code
```

```golang
//kafka_test.go
package kafka_test

//testing code
```

As a quick fix I moved the initiation from `tests->gchat_test->init.go` to `tests->gchat_test->gchat_test.go` and remove `init.go` then it works.

I want to understand why this error is thrown, even though I have the same package name for these files and how to fix it

[image]

Comment: If you'd like to avoid the issue I'd suggest you stop naming your packages in your non-test files `xyz_test`. Just like files that end in `_test.go`, so packages that end in `_test` have special meaning for the go tool.

Comment: @mkopriva Where can I read more on this, and I have two test packages `kafka_test` and `gchat_test`, the former one is not haveing this error.

Comment: Go [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go) and search for "_test" in the text, you'll find multiple instances.

Comment: @Sab I'm guessing go loads the files alphabetically so it works when loading `init.go -> kafka_test.go` but not the other way around, `gchat_test.go -> init.go`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files that don't have a `_test.go` suffix will form the source files of the package. Files that have a `_test.go` suffix are excluded by `go build`. Test files declaring a package with `_test` suffix form a different package.

So basically you have a *normal* package `gchat_test` defined by the non-test file `init.go`, and you have a *test* package `gchat_test` defined by the test files `gchat_test.go`. Whether this will work depends on the Go tool implementation.

**All in all, package names having `_test` should not be used in non-test packages.** `init.go` is a non-test file, it should not declare a test package.

> [Compile packages and dependencies:](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)
>
> When compiling packages, build ignores files that end in '_test.go'.
>
> ---
>
> [Test packages:](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages)
>
> 'Go test' recompiles each package along with any files with names matching the file pattern "*_test.go". These additional files can contain test functions, benchmark functions, fuzz tests and example functions. See 'go help testfunc' for more. Each listed package causes the execution of a separate test binary. Files whose names begin with "_" (including "_test.go") or "." are ignored.
>
> Test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary.